# How to access "move" values from move node in Rain behavior tree?

Tags: unity

I have a blend tree for the NPC that takes an "input magnitude" value--0 to 1.0--for how fast the character should move...and an "angular input" float-- negative pi to positive pi--for how fast the character should turn.

How do I get the rain behavior tree to update these values correctly in the behavior tree "set parameter" leaves?

I see that I can set the parameter with some kind of variable name, but I don't see where I can specify that variable with a script...and I don't see how I can access the "move" instructions given from the move node on the behavior tree, and use them to set the variables either.

How would I accomplish this steering with Rain?